# How to return value of 2 data in foreach which each data has 5 rows in model of codeigniter to view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, return

I have a similar problem that the function only return the first loop data.
The result should be 2 loops and each loop has rows data. 
For example, The first loop is A and has 5 rows data and second loop is B and has 5 rows.
The return value only A with 5 rows, it sould be 10 rows. 5 rows A + 5 rows B.
How is the code should be?
This function in model is bellow

```
function getDataForm($data_search)
{
    $i=0;
    if(!empty($data_search['arr_idacl']))
    {
        foreach($data_search['arr_idacl'] as $idx => $val)
        {
            if(!empty($operatingHour))
            {
                $sql = "SELECT be_acl_resources.description as description,DATE_FORMAT(tbl_camera_detail.start_time,'%d %M %Y ') as datadate, SUM(IF(tbl_consolid_detail.operation = 'plus' AND tbl_consolid_detail.direction = 'IN',tbl_camera_detail.enters,0))+SUM(IF(tbl_consolid_detail.operation = 'minus' AND tbl_consolid_detail.direction = 'IN',tbl_camera_detail.enters*(-1),0))+SUM(IF(tbl_consolid_detail.operation = 'plus' AND tbl_consolid_detail.direction = 'OUT',tbl_camera_detail.exits,0))+SUM(IF(tbl_consolid_detail.operation = 'minus' AND tbl_consolid_detail.direction = 'OUT',tbl_camera_detail.exits*(-1),0)) as total_enter FROM tbl_consolid JOIN tbl_consolid_detail ON tbl_consolid.id = tbl_consolid_detail.consolid_id JOIN tbl_config_data ON tbl_consolid_detail.config_data_id = tbl_config_data.id JOIN tbl_camera ON tbl_config_data.id_acl = tbl_camera.id_acl JOIN tbl_camera_detail ON tbl_camera.id = tbl_camera_detail.camera_id JOIN be_acl_resources ON tbl_consolid.id_acl = be_acl_resources.id WHERE tbl_camera.date >= '".$data_search['start_date']."' AND date_format(tbl_camera_detail.start_time, '%H, %i %S') >= '".$startOpratingHour."' AND date_format(tbl_camera_detail.start_time, '%H, %i %S') <= '".$operatingHour['finish_time']."' AND tbl_camera.date <= '".$data_search['end_date']."' AND tbl_consolid.id_acl = '".$val."' GROUP BY tbl_camera.date";               
                echo $sql;               
                $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                $result_data[] = $query->result();
                //return $result;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $result_data;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare `$result_data = array();` just before `if(!empty($data_search['arr_idacl']))` condition.
2. <strike>Replace `$result_data[] = $query->result();` with `$result_data[$i] = $query->result();`</strike>

   ---

   **Update:**
   Just close to the answer. :) Try this:
   Replace `$result_data[] = $query->result();` with `$result_data[$i][] = $query->result();`

Comment: Still not working. Here is the controler code :    $result['data1'] = $this->database_model->getDataForm($data_search);

   $this->load->view('admin/database/excel',$result); and this is the view code $n=0;
//$data1 = array();
foreach($data1 as $idx => $val)
{

?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $val->datadate; ?></td>
<td><? echo $val->description; ?></td>
<td><? echo $val->total_enter; ?></td>
<td><? echo $number; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php

          
$n++;  
}

Comment: That return only two value A and B. it should each value has rows. for example each value has 5 rows, so it should display 10 rows. AAAAABBBBB.The new code only display two rows A and B, and the values are the sum of 5 rows.

Comment: @Joko: Check my update. My 1st answer would have returned Last value in A and Last value in B. Now My 2nd answer will store 5 values of A and 5 values of B.

Comment: How to display that in view? I use codeigniter. and the code of view like this : <?php
$n=0;

foreach($data1 as $idx => $val)
{

?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $val[$n]->datadate; ?></td>
<td><? echo $val[$n]->description; ?></td>
<td><? echo $val[$n]->total_enter; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
          
$n++;  
}

Comment: If it works, pls post the array structure by editing your question. don't post it in comments.